# Find string in col 1, print col 2 in awk

Tags: macos, awk

I'm on a Mac, and I want to find a field in a CSV file adjacent to a search string

This is going to be a single file with a hard path; here's a sample of it:

```
84:a5:7e:6c:a6:b0, AP-ATC-151g84
84:a5:7e:6c:a6:b1, AP-A88-131g84
84:a5:7e:73:10:32, AP-AG7-133g56
84:a5:7e:73:10:30, AP-ADC-152g81
84:a5:7e:73:10:31, AP-D78-152e80
```

so if my search string is `"84:a5:7e:73:10:32"` 
I want to get returned `"AP-AG7-133g56"`

I had been working within an Applescript, but maybe a shell script will do.

I just need the proper syntax for opening the file and having awk search it. Again, I'm weak conceptually on how shell commands run, how they must be executed, etc

This errors, gives me ("command not found"):

```
set the_file to "/Users/Paw/Desktop/AP-Decoder 3.app/Contents/Resources/BSSIDtable.csv"
set the_val to "70:56:81:cb:a2:dc"
do shell script "'awk $1 ~ the_val {print $2} the_file'"
```

Thank you for coddling me...

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively simple:

```
awk '$1 == "70:56:81:cb:a2:dc," {print "The answer is "$2}' 'BSSIDtable.csv'
```

(the `"The answer is "` text can be omitted if you only wish to see only the data, but this shows you how to get more user-friendly output if desired).

The comma is included since `awk` uses white space for separators so the comma becomes part of column 1.

If the thing you're looking for is in a shell variable, you can use `-v` to provide that to `awk` as an `awk` variable:

```
lookfor="70:56:81:cb:a2:dc,"
awk -v mac=$lookfor '$1 == mac {print "The answer is "$2}' 'BSSIDtable.csv'
```

As an aside, your AppleScript solution is probably not working because the `$1/$2` are being interpreted as shell variable rather than `awk` variables. If you insist on using AppleScript, you will have to figure out how to construct a shell command that quotes the `awk` commands correctly.

My advice is to just use the shell directly, the number of people proficient in that almost certainly *far* outnumber those proficient in AppleScript :-)

Comment: Thnx Diablo! But where in the script would I indicate the file I'm searching?

Comment: @nuthindoin, I've added that to the answer, it's an extra argument to `awk` itself.

Comment: Again, many thanks. Last request, forgive my shell ignorance, but if I wanted to preface the awk result with some text like "The answer is" or whatever... how would that be coded?

Comment: @nuthindoin, no probs, see the update, it's a matter of adding a prefix string to the `print` output.

Comment: OK, of course, can't get the 2 steps to work in conjunction.

This code works, finds the BSSID:
`myBSSID=`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I | grep BSSID | awk '{print $2}'``

but when I try to take that variable (myBSSID) and pass it to Diablo's code, I get EOF errors.

`awk '$1 == "$myBSSID," {print "You're connected to "$2}' '/Users/russell/Desktop/BSSIDtable.txt'`

Comment: @nuthindoin, `awk` variables and shell variables are *distinct* things. Within `awk`, `$myBSSID` means use the `awk` variable `myBSSID` as a field number and look up that field in the current line. You can turn the latter into the former with `-v`: `shellvar=xyzzy ; awk -v awkvar=$shellvar 'BEGIN {print awkvar}' </dev/null`. I've added some extra detail to the answer for that.

Comment: Hi again @paxdiablo, many thanks, Here's the script in entirety below. Not sure where that variable translation should be going _(awk -v etc):_ myBSSID="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framew‌​ork/Versions/A/Resou‌​rces/airport -I | grep BSSID | awk '{print $2}'" awk -v theBSSID=$myBSSID '$1 == theBSSID {print $2}' '/Users/russell/Desktop/BSSIDtable.txt'

Answer (score 0):

if sed is available (normaly on mac, event if not tagged in OP)

simple but read all the file

```
sed -n 's/84:a5:7e:73:10:32,[[:blank:]]*//p' YourFile
```

quit after first occurence (so average of 50% faster on huge file)

```
sed -n -e '/84:a5:7e:73:10:32,[[:blank:]]*/!b' -e 's///p;q' YourFile
```

awk

```
awk '/^84:a5:7e:73:10:32/ {print $2}'
# OR using a variable for batch interaction
awk -v Src='84:a5:7e:73:10:32' '$1 == Src {print $2}'
# OR assuming that case is unknow
awk -v Src='84:a5:7e:73:10:32' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $1 == Src {print $2}'
```

by default it take $0 as compare test if a regex is present, just add the `^` to take first field content